# Electron property inacessible in render.js

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm trying to learn how to build electron apps and I found this Youtube tutorial [Build a Desktop App with Electron... But Should You?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3yqDxhR2XxE) on building a simple screen recording app but i encountered this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'Menu' of 'remote' as it is undefined.
> at render.js:9

Here is the exact code from the tutorial  code

```
const videoElement = document.querySelector('video');
const startBtn = document.getElementById('startBtn');
const stopBtn = document.getElementById('stopBtn');
const videoSelectBtn = document.getElementById('videoSelectBtn');
videoSelectBtn.onclick = getVideoSources;

const {desktopCapturer,remote} = require('electron');

const {Menu} = remote;

async function getVideoSources(){

const inputSources = await desktopCapturer.getSources({
    types:['window','screen']
});
const videoOptionsMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(
    inputSources.map(source =>{
   return{
       label:source.name,
       click:()=>selectSource(souce)
   }
    })
);
videoOptionsMenu.popup();
}
```

What I'm I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in new version of electron. you need to allow your electron app to use remote modules.
add `enableRemoteModule: true` flag in your main electron code.

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 1280,
    height: 960,
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
      enableRemoteModule: true,
     },
  });
```

Comment: That worked ! Thanks!  @sharun , I need to get better at reading docs.